# SQLite multiple references to a single column

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

For example

```
Table1
id|v1|v2|v3
1 |10|20|30
2 |20|30|40
3 |30|40|50

Table2
id |a|b|c
100|2|1|1
200|1|3|2
300|3|2|2
```

Table2.a, b and c should be Foreign Keys to Table1.id.

If I try:

```
CREATE Table2(
id, a, b, c,
FOREIGN KEY(a, b, c) REFERENCES Table1(id));
```

I get: "Error: number of columns in foreign key does not match the number of columns in the referenced table"

If I do

```
CREATE Table2(
id,
a REFERENCES(id),
b REFERENCES(id),
c REFERENCES(id));
```

I just get: "Error: near "id": syntax error"

Comment: So what's the goal here?

Comment: Table1 contains several persons and their relevant data, Table2 contains groups, information about the group and the persons who are in it (the foreign keys). One person can be in multiple groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is more like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Table2 (
  id int,
  a int,
  b int,
  c int,
  FOREIGN KEY(a) REFERENCES Table1(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(b) REFERENCES Table1(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(c) REFERENCES Table1(id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're second attempt wasn't far, you just missed the referenced table name. For single column Foreign Keys, the inline (and unnamed) FK constraint definition is more compact, while for composite FKs, you must specify the FK at the end of the table.

```
C:\Users\DDevienne>sqlite3
SQLite version 3.8.3.1 2014-02-11 14:52:19
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table t1 (id primary key);
sqlite> create table t2 (
   ...> id primary key,
   ...> a references t1(id),
   ...> b references t1(id),
   ...> c references t1(id)
   ...> );
sqlite>
```